# Flutter grid view animations

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-gridview

What package I can use for `grid view` animations? I want remove `grid view` item like in IOS Home Screen App delete, and didn't want create custom animation. There is **package** for do this?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_animated

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_animations

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations

Answer (score -2):

You could give a try to use AnimatedContainer

Change the width from item width to 0, when the tap event occurs.

AnimatedContainer detects that the property width changed and animation is shown.

After finishing animation you can remove that item from list.

Comment: thanks for answer, But I write I didn't want use custom animation

Comment: I don't think there are any library which focuses on this type of animation. It's easy todo using custom animation too.